# How create a controller to import CSV file data into multiple tables in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to import data from a CSV file rows into multiple tables in rails?

I am trying to write a method for uploading and importing a CSV file that has data that will need to go to different tables in a existing database using the smarter_csv gem.

Comment: What are you asking? How to write to a database? How to parse a CSV? How to upload/process files?

Comment: Please make it clearer! What is your current problem?

Answer (score 0):

it is probably not a good idea to everything in a controller. You might want to kick off a background job to process your file after the upload. In your background job , you can write the logic to parse CSV and write to multiple tables.

smarter_csv will parse the csv for you into an array of hashes using CSV.parse function.

Need more info to answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

The question needs to be more specific about what is needed. However, assuming all you need is code to upload and process `".csv"` file, you can modify this snippet to suit your need

```
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Listing.create!( :price => row[0], 
                         :status => row[1], 
                         :beds => row[2], 
                         :baths => row[3], 
                         :category_attributes => {:unit_number => row[4]} ) 
    end
end
```

The snippet assumes that you are working with two tables or models - `Listings` and `Categories`. And that you've set up appropriate relationships on these models